# jsonata merge array with aggreate

Tags: jsonata

with this example https://try.jsonata.org/J_4M9J9JS

from this result
`{ "123": [ { "Price": 34.45, "Qty": 2, "ProductID": 858383 }, { "Price": 34.45, "Qty": 2, "ProductID": 85838388888 } ], "Trilby hat": { "Price": 21.67, "Qty": 1, "ProductID": 858236 } }` 
How can I group the "123". Sum the price, take the first ProductID

I expect this result

`[ { "Price": 68.9, "Qty": 2, "ProductID": 858383 }, { "Price": 21.67, "Qty": 1, "ProductID": 858236 } ]`